# D: How create array of Tuples?

Tags: tuples, d

I am looking at [docs](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html) and can't understand hot can I create array of Tuples. It's compile fine:

```d
auto myDataTuple = tuple(url, path);
```

but this code produce error:

```d
auto myDataTuples [] ~= myDataTuple;
```

> Error: no identifier for declarator myDataTuples[].

It's can't understand type for `myDataTuples` or what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't append to a declaration since it doesn't exist yet.

The type `tuple(x, y)` returns is `Tuple!(typeof(x), typeof(y))`. You can make an array of them. So if url and path are both strings, try:

```d
Tuple!(string, string)[] myDataTuple; // the [] makes an array
myDataTuple ~= tuple(url, path);
```

PS: it is my opinion that structs are better than tuples basically all the time. (a Tuple is just a generated struct anyway). You can probably also do `struct MyData { string url; string path; }` and use `MyData` everywhere too. It is easier to realize what it is later.

Comment: Thanks Adam! 
But could I get access to tuple element not for index like `[0]` but for name like: tuple["url"] (I talk about single tuple, not about array of them)

Comment: Then you'd have to name them too... that's like `Tuple!(string, "url", string, "path")` http://dpldocs.info/experimental-docs/std.typecons.Tuple.html

Comment: The only time I've seen that a tuple was more interesting than a struct was for a MRV that could directly be used as parameters in a function call with unpacking  `call(aggregate.getMRV[0..$])`, which is not possible with structs.

Comment: Every time I see "not possible", I answer "challenge accepted" :) The `.tupleof` property on structs yields such an expansion. Behold: `struct Test {
 int a;
 string b;
}

void foo(int, string) {}

void main() {
 Test test;
 foo(test.tupleof);
}`

Answer (score 3):

To define an array using a set of existing variables and values you can list them inside braces [] and declare the array just like an ordinary variable:

```cpp
string url, path;
auto myDataTuple = tuple(url, path);
auto myDataTuples = [myDataTuple];
// Print out the type for better understanding: Tuple!(string, string)[]
writeln(typeof(myDataTuples).stringof);
```

This creates a new dynamic array with one element that can be append to.

Appending to an existing array works like this:

```cpp
// Append an item (variable and literal)
myDataTuples ~= anotherTuple;
myDataTuples ~= tuple(url2, path2);

// Append an array (variable and literal)
myDataTuples ~= anotherArray;
myDataTuples ~= [tuple(url3, path3), tuple(url4, path4)];
```